# Comma with OR in a verb list containing in an introductory phrase

Tags: conjunctions, commas, lists

Here is a sentence from [the New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2011/09/09/technology/google-details-and-defends-its-use-of-electricity.html).

> Every time a person runs a Google search, watches a YouTube video or sends a message through Gmail, the company’s data centers full of computers use electricity.

The initial pharse in the sentence has a list of verbs: runs, watches, and sends. And in American English, we often add the oxford comma in a list. So, why the comma is missing before "or?"

NYTimes writes in American English, so there must be an oxford comma.

Any thoughts on it are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The New York Times stylebook
> "In general, do not use a comma before and or or in a series."

(quoted in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma#Mainly_American_style_guides_opposing_typical_use))

It is not the case that American English always uses an Oxford comma, though it is more common in America.  In particular the NY Times does not.

Comment: Additional info: their rationale apparently is "news writing has traditionally omitted the serial comma — perhaps seeking a more rapid feeling in the prose, or perhaps to save time and effort in the old days of manual typesetting" https://afterdeadline.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/06/23/faqs-on-style-2/